# Background package produces background on every page, despite firstpage=false

Tags: backgrounds

In the following example, pagenumber is printed on every page.
What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{angle=0,  
  scale=1, 
  color=blue, 
  firstpage=false,
  position=current page.south west, 
  hshift=44pt,
  vshift=460pt,
  contents={Page \thepage}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

   \lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: From the documentation about the key `firstpage`: This boolean option allows the user to specify, setting the value `true`, that the background material must be displayed only in the first page of the document. The default value is `false`.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation about the key `firstpage` (top of page 3 in the manual):

> This boolean option allows the user to specify, setting the value `true`, that the background material must be displayed only in the first page of the document. The default value is `false`.

So this is the expected behavior. You have to conditionally insert the material, instead:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{angle=0,
  scale=1,
  color=blue,
  position=current page.south west,
  hshift=44pt,
  vshift=460pt,
  contents={\ifnum\value{page}=1 \else Page \thepage\fi}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

   \lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Saved my day man

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of the 'background' package provides a way easier solution to this:

You can use the command `\NoBgThispage` on the particular page, where you don't want the background image to appear.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{background}
    \backgroundsetup{angle=0,
      scale=1,
      color=blue,
      position=current page.south west,
      hshift=44pt,
      vshift=460pt,
      contents={\thepage}
    }
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \pagestyle{empty}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}

      \NoBgThispage
      \lipsum[1-15]

    \end{document}
```