# use background package，how to make first page haven't the background image?

Tags: backgrounds

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{scale=1,angle=0,opacity=0.1,contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{lion600.png}}}
\begin{document}
\author{SimonZhou}
\title{手册}
\date{2021年6月24日——\today}

\frontmatter
\section{文档来源}
此文档内容主要来源于\href{http://xyoshiki.web.fc2.com/index.html}{xyoshiki}、\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{tex.stackexchange}和\href{https://github.com/CTeX-org/forum}{CTeX-org}。

\section{文档说明}
此文档所用模板是自己依托于ctexbook模板结合其他模板进行整合而成，多有不足与缺漏之处，敬请指正。本人会在力所能及范围内对一些宏包与命令进行注释，以帮助阅读.tex时能更好的理解。
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104057/how-can-i-add-a-background-to-every-page-except-the-first?rq=1

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201232/background-package-produces-background-on-every-page-despite-f

Comment: Thank your answer.But don't solute the question.